# How to swap SVG Fill Color on MouseOver?

Tags: wpf, svg, binding, fill, sharpvectors

I'm using [SharpVectors](http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/) to embed svg file in my XAML.

Here is my `Button` `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
<Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <svgc:SvgViewbox x:Name="svgIcon" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="Uniform" />
        <customUserControl:ExtendedBinding Grid.Column="0"
                                           Source="{Binding ElementName=svgIcon,Path=Source,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                           Target="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Focusable="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And here is an example of creating a button:

```
<Button Content="Text" Tag="../../../../Assets/Icons/cross.svg" Click="OnClick"/>
```

What I obtain is a SVG icon with a text inside my button.

Now I'd like to change the background color of my SVG on `MouseOver` (exactly the same behaviour asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25574053/2965109), the difference is that I do not have a "Fill" tag in my `svgc:SvgViewbox`.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Update:
My SVG file is a standard SVG, like this:

```
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M311.517,14.053c-99.265,0-180.024,80.66-180.024,179.805c0,41.538,14.182,79.827,37.955,110.303L0,451.176l22.889,26.313    l170.577-147.994c31.628,27.496,72.926,44.168,118.051,44.168c99.266,0,180.025-80.661,180.025-179.805    C491.542,94.713,410.784,14.053,311.517,14.053z M311.517,353.663c-88.237,0-160.024-71.688-160.024-159.805    S223.279,34.053,311.517,34.053s160.025,71.688,160.025,159.805S399.755,353.663,311.517,353.663z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
        <polygon points="322.447,122.812 300.587,122.812 300.587,182.928 240.471,182.928 240.471,204.788 300.587,204.788     300.587,264.904 322.447,264.904 322.447,204.788 382.563,204.788 382.563,182.928 322.447,182.928   " fill="#000000"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

Comment: working on it , wait

Comment: Got stuck on same problem. Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be multiple `GeomtryDrawing` 's in your `svg XAML` like below :

```
<DrawingGroup>
   <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF71BF22">
        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M546.394,327.725L536.856,272.111 507.584,214.272C507.584,214.272,493.855,193.075,471.075,197.47L498.963,334.022 546.394,327.725z" />
        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
   </GeometryDrawing>
```

Search for all such `Brush` in your code and change their values, thus creating two copies of your `SVG XAML`, then using `Trigger` swap these on `MouseOver`.

EDIT #1 (based on OP's 1st comment)

You can use an `AttachedProperty` to handle `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events for your `Path`. This AP allows you to set the transparency level.
Your `Path` must be under `Grid`.

```
public static byte GetSvgProp(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (byte)obj.GetValue(SvgPropProperty);
}

public static void SetSvgProp(DependencyObject obj, byte value)
{
    obj.SetValue(SvgPropProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SvgProp.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SvgPropProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SvgProp", typeof(byte), typeof(Window2), new PropertyMetadata((byte)0xFF, new PropertyChangedCallback(SvgPropChanged)));

private static void SvgPropChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{       
    ((Grid)d).Loaded += (s, args) => {

        var paths = ((Grid)s).Children.OfType<Path>();
        foreach (Path p in paths)
        {
            p.MouseEnter += (s1, args1) => {
                Path p1 = (Path)s1;
                p1.Tag = p1.Fill; // save old value
                var c = ((SolidColorBrush)p1.Fill).Color;
                Color newColor = new Color() { A=(byte)e.NewValue, R = c.R, G = c.G, B = c.B };
                p1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = newColor };
            };
            p.MouseLeave += (s2, args2) => {
                Path p2 = (Path)s2;
                //p2.Fill.Opacity = 1.0;
                p2.Fill = (Brush)p2.Tag; // revert back to old value
            };
        }

    };
}
```

Assuming your SVG code is in a `Grid` :

```
<Grid local:Window2.SvgProp="0x23">
            <Path Fill="Red" Data="M311.517,14.053c-99.265,0-180.024,80.66-180.024,179.805c0,41.538,14.182,79.827,37.955,110.303L0,451.176l22.889,26.313    l170.577-147.994c31.628,27.496,72.926,44.168,118.051,44.168c99.266,0,180.025-80.661,180.025-179.805    C491.542,94.713,410.784,14.053,311.517,14.053z M311.517,353.663c-88.237,0-160.024-71.688-160.024-159.805    S223.279,34.053,311.517,34.053s160.025,71.688,160.025,159.805S399.755,353.663,311.517,353.663z"/>                    
            <Polygon Points="322.447,122.812 300.587,122.812 300.587,182.928 240.471,182.928 240.471,204.788 300.587,204.788     300.587,264.904 322.447,264.904 322.447,204.788 382.563,204.788 382.563,182.928 322.447,182.928   " Fill="#000000"/>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not what I need: I don't want, if possible, to create multiple copies of my svg, I'd like to change the svg color directly by code; unless I have to duplicate all my icons. I added also a SVG file example in my question ;)

Comment: @Rowandish I have added more answer, see and tell if it meets your needs. It is working !

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to get it working via reflection.

*Also opened an issue at the github (https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/issues/88) repo to make the properties public and easily access them.*

```
SvgDrawingCanvas canvas = (SvgDrawingCanvas) fooSvgViewbox.Child;
List<Drawing> drawings = (List<Drawing>)typeof(SvgDrawingCanvas).GetField("_drawObjects", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(canvas);

foreach (Drawing drawing in drawings)
{
    if (drawing is GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing)
    {
        geometryDrawing.Brush = Brushes.BlueViolet;
    }
}
```

If you look at the class code (https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/blob/master/Source/SharpVectorRuntimeWpf/SvgDrawingCanvas.cs#L49) you will see the private modifier for the drawn objects. Via reflection it is possible to access and modify the items. Now you are able to make your own AttachedBehavior or custom binding!